# C++ Future handling

Tags: c++, api, asynchronous, promise, future

I'm building a C++ program which is using API to try and acquire some data about packages tracking info and some of those methods are returning futures, and if the future is fulfilled, I want to return it to the main program. Consider the following:

```
std::future<ApiClass> myMethodReturningFuture() {
    /* some processing */
    std::future<ApiClass> future = api.call();
    return future;
}
```

My question is how to correctly handle the future (eg. check if it contains correct info, calling future.valid() seems to always return 1). Also, if the future is not fully valid, how to return NULL or nullptr from this function ? Let's consider this situation:

```
std::future<ApiClass> myMethodReturningFuture() {
    /* some processing */
    try {
        std::future<ApiClass> future = api.call();
        return future;
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        return nullptr // or NULL;
    }
}
```

The snippet above doesn't compile. Even if I make a function to return a pointer, I get an error about "using deleted function std::future". Something like this:

```
std::future<ApiClass>* myMethodReturningFuture() {
    /* some processing */
    try {
        std::future<ApiClass>* future = &api.call();
        return future;
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        return nullptr // or NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: `std::future::valid()` should return `false` from a default constructed future `std::future<ApiClass>();`. You could return one of those.

Comment: What do you mean *if the future is not fully valid*? If there is no good way to handle an exception that's thrown in this method, you should probably catch it higher up the call chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `future` is basically a wrapper around some shared state. `valid` is telling you whether the `future` actually has some shared state or not.

A `future` will have no shared state if it was default constructed, or if its shared state has already been retrieved, or if it was the source of a move, so some other `future` now owns the shared state this one used to.

At least as I understand what you're writing, chances are pretty good that you really want to just return the `future` as is, and have no reason to check whether it's valid before you return it--in particular, if you receive a `future` that's not valid, the equivalent of a "null future" that you'd return to signal that would be a default-constructed `future` that would signal "not present" ...by its `valid` returning `false`. In other words, you'd signal the lack of a `future` by returning exactly the same sort of one as you received in the first place.

I suppose you *could* separate out the signaling of "not present" from the `future` if you really wanted to. For example, you could define your function something like this:

```cpp
std::optional<std::future<ApiClass>> myMethodReturningFuture() {
```

In an ideal<sup>1</sup> world with every class fully decomposed and having only a single responsibility, `std::future` probably wouldn't exist--you'd instead have something like `std::optional<std::shared_state<T>>` in its place, and the `optional` part would be responsible for saying whether it's present or not, and the `shared_state` would *only* deal with being shared state. But that's not the world we live in, so `future`'s `valid` is basically acting like the `optional`, and telling you whether the shared state is present or not.

If you were going to do this, you'd need to account for the fact that a `future` is moveable but not copyable, so when you assign one to a variable, you need to use `std::move` to get it back out of that variable. For example, here's some trivial (but complete) code to do the check and return an `std::optional<std::future<T>>`:

```cpp
#include <optional>
#include <future>

struct ApiClass {
    int i;
};

struct Api { 
    std::future<ApiClass> call() const {
        // create and return a (trivial) future.
        return std::async(std::launch::async, []{ return ApiClass {1}; });
    }
};

std::optional<std::future<ApiClass>> myMethodReturningFuture() {
    Api api;
    // here we create a `future` object, so it's an lvalue, not an rvalue
    std::future<ApiClass> future {api.call()};
    // so when we want to create our optional<future>, we need to tell the
    // compiler to move instead of copying the object we created:
    return future.valid() == 1 ? std::make_optional(std::move(future)) : std::nullopt;
}
```

---

<sup>1. Well, ideal from one viewpoint. Frankly, I'm not sure this design would turn out so ideal in real use. Then again, I'm not sure `future` is entirely ideal in real use either.</sup>

Comment: Thanks! I'm having some problems with using optional though. I can't get this to compile, and I'm not sure why:
`std::optional<std::future<ApiClass>> myMethodReturningFuture() {
        std::future<ApiClass> future = api.call(); return fut.valid() == 1 ? std::make_optional(future) : std::nullopt;
 }
`
Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::optional<std::future<ApiClass> >::optional(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’

This is the error I'm getting

Comment: @linnoob: I've edited some demonstration code into the answer.

Comment: That's brilliant. Thank you very much!